# Android XML Document. How to read info about document encdoding?

Tags: android, xml

I have XML with starts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
```

How in android get encoding?

document.inputEncoding=null ?

here full info about object

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SAXParser`, if only to read that one element.

Comment: Does SAXParser on method startEntity starts from xml? As i know, it's starts from root entity - not from xml.